# win32 console - form example!

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build a simple form in a c++ win32 console application.
instead of using cin and keep prompting the user to enter the details, i would like to display the form labels then using the tab key, allow the user to tab through.

What is the simplest way of doing this, without having to use ncurses?

all I need is cout the below all at once:

```
Name:
Username:
Email:
```

set the cursor position next to name Field, then each time you hit tab, i gotoxy, and set the cursor at the next position, then set the the cin to the next variable
eg. 
at startup

```
gotoxy(nameX, nameY);
cin >> name;
```

Hit Tab/enter

```
gotoxy(usernameX, usernameY);
cin >> username;
```

Hit Tab/enter

```
gotoxy(emailX, emailY);
cin >> email;
```

is this even doable?

I tried while loops with, GetAsyncKeyState, and keyboard events, but the cin is not working properly in that loop.

is there any good example for a super simple form, or reference for doing that?
I know how to SetConsoleCursorPosition, but how to implement the tabbing while still being able to capture cin?

thanks

Comment: It's a Uni project required to be a win32 console app, where they wanted to see the usage of cout, cin, and a whole bunch of iostream functions. and That's why i haven't used ncurses, because it takes control of the screen and I won't be able to use cout, cin etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the simplest way of doing
>   this, without having to use ncurses?

Using **ncurses** (or an equivalent library) *is* the simple way to do this, by far.

You seem to forget that *tab* is just another character when reading by lines (as in `cin>>name;`). To emulate **ncurses**, your program would need to handle multiple classes of key strokes (backspace, tab, arrows, characters, digits, even function keys, etc.), do whatever is appropriate, properly maintain the state of the screen, and the position of the cursor -- all to read three text fields from the user.

Consider spending a few hours perusing the [source code](http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/ncurses/ncurses-5.5.tar.gz), even if you don't use it you might learn quite a lot (that's a serious suggestion, BTW).

Comment: Thanks NVRam, at least now I know not to die trying without using ncurses. If ncurses is the solution, then I assume the Uni is not expecting we use it. So back to the dodgy prompts, and stuff user experience. Ncurses is great, I have implemented earlier when i was researching TUI libraries. Thanks again, your answer concludes it.